# cx_oracle python iteration

Tags: python, sql, database, iteration, cx-oracle

I have my python script which reads an excel column row by row and returns all rows str(values).
I want to write another script which will allow put these values to sql db. I've already written connect method:

```
def db_connect():
    adr = 'some_addr'
    uid = 'some_uid'
    pwd = 'pwd'
    port = port

    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(adr, port, SID)
    db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'pass', dsn_tns)

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('update TABLE set ROW = 666 where ANOTHER_ROW is null')
    db.commit()
```

This method does an update but it sets 666 for ALL rows. How to do it by kind of iteration in sql? For example, first row of output == 1, second == 23, third == 888.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "rownum" expression, as in:

```
cur.execute("update TABLE set ROW = rownum where ANOTHER_ROW is null")
```

This will start with the value 1 and increment up by one for each row updated.

If you want more control over the value to set, you can also do the following in PL/SQL (untested):

```
cur.execute("""
        declare
            t_NewValue number;
            cursor c_Data is
                select ROW, ANOTHER_ROW
                from TABLE
                where ANOTHER_ROW is null
                for update;
        begin
            t_NewValue := 1;
            for row in c_Data loop
                update TABLE set ROW = t_NewValue
                where current of c_Data;

                t_NewValue := t_NewValue + 1;
            end loop;
        end;""")
```

This gives you the most control. You can use whatever logic you require to control what the new value should be.

Comment: Ofcourse it works, but it isn't what I want to achieve. Check my answer please, i've added more code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do here it should be done in two phases. First select all rows for update (based on chosen condition), then you can iteratively update each of these rows.

It cannot be done in single query (or on only single condition that does not change through a number of queries), because SQL works on sets, that's why each time your query is executed you are updating whole table, and in the end only getting result of the last query.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at another method which is writing to excel:

```
adr = 'some_addr'
uid = 'some_uid'
pwd = 'pwd'
port = port

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(adr, port, SID)
db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'pass', dsn_tns)

cur = db.cursor()

cells = excel.read_from_cell()
indices_and_statuses = []
stat = execute_script(some_js)
for req_id in cells:
    indices_and_statuses.append((cells.index(req_id), stat))
    cur.execute("""update TABLE set ROW ="""+"'"+req_id+"'"+"""where ANOTHER_ROW is null""")
    db.commit()
db.close()
```

And in this code when you put     print(req_id) in this FOR statement, you will see that req_id is changing. But in DB only the last req_id is saved.

Comment: This is simply because you are performing an update that updates each and every row as many times as there are cells! If you want to iterate over the rows and update at the same time you'll want to use PL/SQL in order to avoid the constant round-trips to the database. Let me know if you want me to adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga, could you give me an example please?

Comment: I added an example.